# NiFi custom processor won't publish data after sometime to next processor

Tags: apache, apache-nifi

I have written the redis data enricher which will get the rules and timeout key from the redis based on the macid but it is working for sometime and after sometime it is not sending flowfile to next processor(it will be in running state but won't send flowfile to next processor). Nifi is working in cluster mode is there any thing wrong in the below processor(RedisDataEnricher).

In the below code I am taking redis connection only once and after that I'm using the same connection for fecthing data from redis.

```
public class RedisDataEnricher extends AbstractProcessor {

    private volatile Jedis jedis;


    public static final PropertyDescriptor ConnectionHost = new PropertyDescriptor
            .Builder().name("ConnectionHost")
            .displayName("ConnectionHost")
            .description("ConnectionHost")
            .required(true)
            .addValidator(StandardValidators.NON_EMPTY_VALIDATOR)
            .build();
    public static final PropertyDescriptor ConnectionPort = new PropertyDescriptor
            .Builder().name("ConnectionPort")
            .displayName("ConnectionPort")
            .description("ConnectionPort")
            .required(true)
            .addValidator(StandardValidators.NON_EMPTY_VALIDATOR)
            .build();

    public static final PropertyDescriptor JSONKEY = new PropertyDescriptor
            .Builder().name("JSONKEY")
            .displayName("JSONKEY")
            .description("JSON key to be fetched from input")
            .required(true)
            .addValidator(StandardValidators.NON_EMPTY_VALIDATOR)
            .build();
    public static final PropertyDescriptor MACIDKEY = new PropertyDescriptor
            .Builder().name("MACIDKEY")
            .displayName("MACIDKEY")
            .description("MACIDKEY to be fetched from input")
            .required(true)
            .addValidator(StandardValidators.NON_EMPTY_VALIDATOR)
            .build();

    public static final Relationship SUCCESS = new Relationship.Builder()
            .name("SUCCESS")
            .description("SUCCESS")
            .build();
    public static final Relationship FAILURE = new Relationship.Builder()
            .name("FAILURE")
            .description("FAILURE")
            .build();

    private List<PropertyDescriptor> descriptors;

    private Set<Relationship> relationships;

    @Override
    protected void init(final ProcessorInitializationContext context) {
        final List<PropertyDescriptor> descriptors = new ArrayList<PropertyDescriptor>();
        descriptors.add(JSONKEY);
        descriptors.add(MACIDKEY);
        descriptors.add(ConnectionHost);
        descriptors.add(ConnectionPort);
        this.descriptors = Collections.unmodifiableList(descriptors);

        final Set<Relationship> relationships = new HashSet<Relationship>();
        relationships.add(SUCCESS);
        relationships.add(FAILURE);
        this.relationships = Collections.unmodifiableSet(relationships);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Relationship> getRelationships() {
        return this.relationships;
    }

    @Override
    public final List<PropertyDescriptor> getSupportedPropertyDescriptors() {
        return descriptors;
    }

    @OnScheduled
    public void onScheduled(final ProcessContext context) {
        try {
            jedis = new Jedis(context.getProperty("ConnectionHost").toString(),Integer.parseInt(context.getProperty("ConnectionPort").toString()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            getLogger().error("Unable to establish Redis connection.");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onTrigger(final ProcessContext context, final ProcessSession session) throws ProcessException {
        FlowFile flowFile = session.get();
        if ( flowFile == null ) {
            return;
        }

        else{
            try{
                InputStream inputStream = session.read(flowFile);
                StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
                IOUtils.copy(inputStream, writer, "UTF-8");
                Jedis jedis1=jedis;
                JSONObject json=new JSONObject(writer.toString());
                inputStream.close();
                JSONObject json1=new JSONObject();
                String rules=jedis1.hget(json.getJSONObject(context.getProperty("JSONKEY").toString()).getString(context.getProperty("MACIDKEY").toString()), "rules");
                json1.put("data", json.getJSONObject(context.getProperty("JSONKEY").toString()));
                json1.put("timeOut", jedis1.hget(json.getJSONObject(context.getProperty("JSONKEY").toString()).getString(context.getProperty("MACIDKEY").toString()),"timeOut"));
                json1.put("rules", rules!=null?new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(rules.split(" , "))):new ArrayList<>());
                flowFile = session.write(flowFile, new OutputStreamCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void process(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
                        out.write(json1.toString().getBytes());
                    }


            });
                flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, "OutBound", jedis1.hget(json.getJSONObject(context.getProperty("JSONKEY").toString()).getString(context.getProperty("MACIDKEY").toString()),"OutBound"));
                session.transfer(flowFile, SUCCESS);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                session.transfer(flowFile, FAILURE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why there is no session.commit ?

Comment: is flowfile transfer not enough, because it works for some time after that it will fail

Comment: AbstractProcessor will call session.commit() after onTrigger

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of your flow in the state where you say it stopped working? including the queue before the processor and after the processor

Comment: Actually my redis server is going down, so it is transferring flowfile for faliure relation. But once it is up, also it is not flowing to success relation can you suggest if any code improvements is required. If I stop and start the processor it is working fine.